# systemd unit config that waits for PPPoe connection

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, ppp

On Ubuntu 16.04LTS I'm having trouble getting my service to wait for my PPPoe internet connection before starting.

My unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Home Assistant
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
ExecStart=/srv/homeassistant/bin/hass -c "/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
    mtu 1508

auto enp4s0.35
iface enp4s0.35 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp4s0
    mtu 1508

auto wan
iface wan inet ppp
   provider bell

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
   address 192.168.80.1
   network 192.168.80.0
   broadcast 192.168.80.255
```

If I run `pon bell` there is a considerable delay (10-20s) between the command finishing execution and when the interface appears in `ifconfig`.

I believe homeassistant is starting early because its logs contain errors about failing to reach public endpoints, which doesn't occur if I restart the service manually after boot.

How can I get the service to wait properly?

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration for hass uses domain names instead of IP addresses, you could try to add `nss-lookup.target` at the end, after a space, on the `After=` line...

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#nss-lookup.target